# Clear a PATH from a fabric.js canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, path, fabricjs

I am trying to clear a path from my canvas. I can retrieve the original path like:

```
M0,0V1076H765s38.17-107,164.91-107c119.77,4.92,155.09,107,155.09,107h759V0Z
```

Or i can convert it to points with a library I have ([SVGtoWKT](https://github.com/davidmcclure/svg-to-wkt))

Now I need to clear the canvas on this area, so it is totally empty and transparent, before I export it to a PNG (exports works fine).

I know I can "clearRect" an area from a canvas, but I can have a lot of different paths, where I can have arcs, diagonals, ...

Does fabric.js have a native solution ? Or is there a plugin for canvas that I could use ?

Comment: After clearing the context you have to redraw everything except the path.

Comment: It's actually a little bit more complicated than that.. I have a canvas where the user will drag and drop different objects, put a background on the background allowed part. Then there is overlays parts where everything has to be deleted (pictures will be printed on those parts). Example of a simple creation: https://ibb.co/8b8K1WB. All the white part will have to be cropped, but the red pic will be cut in two.

Comment: do you render the path as a fabric.js object?

Comment: yes currently 100% is done with fabric